# Why can't I shrink a virtual disk in Hyper-V

Tags: virtual-machine, vhd, diskpart, vhdx

I have a virtual machine running Ubuntu 12.04 which I created using Hyper-V in a Windows 8.1 host. At one point, I had a very large file in my virtual machine which caused my dynamically expanding hard drive to grow to almost 200 GB. Since then, I have removed the file and I am trying to shrink the hard drive file back down. As you can see from this screenshot of GParted from within Ubuntu, I am not using a lot of disk storage:

[image: 192 GiB unused]

I tried using the "compact disk" option within Hyper-V settings; however, this did not affect the size of the vhdx file in the host which remains close to 200 GB in size. I also tried following [these instructions](https://fiddley.wordpress.com/2014/01/27/dynamically-expanding-vhd-not-compacting-in-hyper-v/) for using Windows' `diskpart` utility, but this also had no effect. Am I missing something? Is there something else I can try?

Comment: @Ramhound I think either I'm not understanding what you're saying or you're not understanding what I'm saying. I don't want to reduce the capacity of the virtual hard drive. I want that to remain 200 GB. I just want to reduce the size of the .vhdx file because the drive is currently only storing 6 GB of data.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest you take steps to make a copy of the .vhdx before you modify it.  In order to change the size of an existing .vhdx file, you should first mount the virtual hdd by using the command: **mount-vhd** in an elevated PowerShell command prompt.

> ```
> mount-vhd \\FS01\vmdata\AS02_C.vhdx -passthru | get-disk | get-partition | get-volume
> ```

The output of the command will look like

> [image]

If you want to change the size of one of the partitions by using: **resize-partition** in an elevated PowerShell command prompt.

> ```
> resize-partition -driveletter E -size 35GB
> ```

Before you can change the size of the virtual hdd you will have to use the command: **dismount-vhd** in an elevated PowerShell command prompt.

> ```
> dismount-vhd \\FS01\vmdata\AS02_C.vhdx
> ```

Once you have modified the partition size and dismounted the virtual HDD, you can modify the size of the virtual hdd by using the command: **resize-vhd** in an elevated PowerShell command prompt.

> resize-vhd \FS01\vmdata\AS02_C.vhdx -ToMinimumSize

Source: [Resize-VHD](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/itpro/powershell/windows/hyper-v/resize-vhd)

Comment: This process seems to work specifically for NTFS drives. The one I'm dealing with is ext4. Running the first command in your answer yields no output at all.

Comment: This does not work for VHDs with Linux on it. After any resize attempts with `cmdlets` or other options it destroys boot partitions and partition table completely.

Comment: @Ramhound unfortunately, it is not OS agnostic. Ubuntu boots after copying or converting VHD to both fixed or dynamic VHDX. No problem there. But it breaks after Resize-VHD either with specific size or to minimum size. It destroys partition table if you try to shrink.